# localStorage Array split

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, local-storage

I have a script to put formdata into localStorage. The data saved in an array. I want that the elements in the array where list without brackets and underneath eachother. Does somebody have a hint for me how to do that?

The array and the output in the div looks like this:

```
[[{"EMail":"testmail@test.com","Salutaion":"Mr","FirstName":"Test","Name":"Testname"},{"EMail":"testy@test.com","Salutaion":"Mrs","FirstName":"Testy","Name":"TestyFemale"}]]
```

The script to show the array in a div:

```
var output = ''; 

for (var key in localStorage) {
  output = output+(key + ':' +localStorage[key])+'\n';
}
$('#divtoshowarray').html(output);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6x490kot/

Comment: Storing data in localStorage and displaying it in the page are two completely different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the updated code

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var testObject = { 'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3 };

    localStorage.setItem('testObject', JSON.stringify(testObject));

    var output = ''; 
    var objectFromLS = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('testObject'));
    for (var key in objectFromLS) {
        if (objectFromLS.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      output = output+(key + ':<br>' +objectFromLS[key])+'\n';
        }
    }
    $('#divtoshowarray').html(output);
});
```

**Key Points**

1. You want to iterate on testObject data stored in localStorage. So you need to get testObject from localStorage and iterate on it. Please note, localStorage.getItem will return string, so, you need to parse it so as to return a JSON.
2. Then you need to iterate on the object, to paint key value pair.

For reference - https://jsfiddle.net/6x490kot/1/